# Deserialize JSON to class instance

Tags: java, jackson, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have a class that is being sent through RabbitMQ as a message, on the sender service, it is defined like:

```
public final class User implements Serializable {

    private String nome;
    private String cognome;

    public User(@JsonProperty("nome") String nome,
                @JsonProperty("cognome") String cognome) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.cognome = cognome;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public String getCognome() {
        return cognome;
    }

    public User(){}
}
```

and on the receiver service:

```
@Document
public class Persona {

    @Id
    @JsonProperty
    public ObjectId id;

    private String nome;

    private String cognome;

    public String getId() {
        return id.toHexString();
    }

    public void setId(ObjectId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getCognome() {
        return cognome;
    }

    public void setCognome(String cognome) {
        this.cognome = cognome;
    }

    public Persona(ObjectId id, String nome, String cognome) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.cognome = cognome;
    }

    public Persona(){}
}
```

In receiver controller, I have the following method, which should take that message, cast it to an object, and save it in a database, it looks like:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = {"default_parser_q"})
    public void receiveMessage(final Message message){
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
                .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
                .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NULL_FOR_PRIMITIVES, false);

        mapper.readValue(message.getBody(), Persona.class);
        System.out.println(message.toString() + "the message has been received");
    }
```

The problem is that I'm getting an exception on the `readValue()` method, specifically:

> Unhandled exceptions: java.io.IOException, com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException, com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException

The message(JSON) being sent in this case, is:

```
{
  'nome': "John",
  'cognome': "Doe"
}
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Edit: Adding the stack trace as requested.

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `demo.com.fetcherservice.models.Persona` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('{
>                   "nome": "John",
>                   "cognome": "Doe"
>               }')
>        at [Source: (byte[])""{\n\t\t\t\"nome\": \"John\",\n\t\t\t\"cognome\": \"Doe\"\n\t\t}""; line: 1, column: 1]
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1343)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1032)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ValueInstantiator._createFromStringFallbacks(ValueInstantiator.java:371)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createFromString(StdValueInstantiator.java:323)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromString(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1373)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:171)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:161)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3091)
>           at kdmforce.com.fetcherservice.services.FetcherService.receiveMessage(FetcherService.java:23)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:171)
>           at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:120)
>           at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:50)
>           at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:196)
>           at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:129)
>           at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1552)
>           at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1478)
>           at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1466)
>           at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1461)
>           at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1410)
>           at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:870)
>           at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:854)
>           at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:78)
>           at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1137)
>           at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1043)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>       com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `demo.com.fetcherservice.models.Persona` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('{
>                   "nome": "John",
>                   "cognome": "Doe"
>               }')
>        at [Source: (byte[])""{\n\t\t\t\"nome\": \"John\",\n\t\t\t\"cognome\": \"Doe\"\n\t\t}""; line: 1, column: 1]
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1343)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1032)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ValueInstantiator._createFromStringFallbacks(ValueInstantiator.java:371)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createFromString(StdValueInstantiator.java:323)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromString(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1373)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:171)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:161)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3091)
>           at kdmforce.com.fetcherservice.services.FetcherService.receiveMessage(FetcherService.java:23)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:171)
>           at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:120)
>           at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:50)
>           at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:196)
>           at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:129)
>           at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1552)
>           at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1478)
>           at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1466)
>           at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1461)
>           at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1410)
>           at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:870)
>           at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:854)
>           at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:78)
>           at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1137)
>           at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1043)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Can you add the full stacktrace?

Comment: You can set DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_MISSING_CREATOR_PROPERTIES to false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the behaviour I've seen for Kafka, since you're also using Spring I assume it's the same.

Your sending end converts the object into Json and then sends it as a String - hence the escaped quotes in the error message (`\"nome\": \"John\",\n\t\t\t\"cognome\": \"Doe\"`).

You need to declare JsonSerializer on the sender side and then pass it your `User`, or - if you manually create the Json String - declare that it's a byte array so Spring doesn't try to escape the quotes and whitespaces.

Comment: I was sending the data as String, changing it to User resolved it. It makes NO sense how it is casting it behind the scenes to send it as a String to cast it back on the receiving end tho. Thank you!

Comment: `>"Makes no sense"` - see my answer for why that happens.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are "double" encoding the JSON.

If you are sending a JSON String using the `RabbitTemplate`, you should NOT be using a JSON message converter, because it will re-encode the already encoded JSON.

Either use `template.send(msg)` (with the `messageProperties.contentType()` set to `application/json`) or, if you use `convertAndSend()`, use a `SimpleMessageConverter` in the template and

```
 template.convertAndSend(exchange, rk, myJsonStrng, msg -> {
        msg.getMessageProperties().setContentType("application/json");
        return msg;
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

**@Edit3:** Finally found a matchig input that result in the stacktrace you posted

The problem is that your input to the jackson mapper is this:

```
\"{\\n\\t\\t\\t\\\"nome\\\": \\\"John\\\",\\n\\t\\t\\t\\\"cognome\\\": \\\"Doe\\\"\\n\\t\\t}\"
```

Jackson thinks its a single value but fails to map it to a creator.

The correct input would look like this

```
{\n\t\t\t\"nome\": \"John\",\n\t\t\t\"cognome\": \"Doe\"\n\t\t}
```

As `@daniu` posted this is likely due to some `Spring` interference elsewhere.

Comment: Yeah, `@Document` is for mongodb but that is indeed unrelated.

Comment: Tried it and still nothing. It seems like it simply won't accept deserialize the JSON string...

Comment: Managed to identify the incorrect input that results in the stacktrace you have provided. As `@daniu` answered, this is most likely due to some spring interference.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can write complex custom JSON configuration, but the simplest solution would be to de-serialize your message back into `User` class and then add a constructor to your `Persona` class that takes `id` and `User` class as parameters